# Visual Studio 2022 stuck on cherry pick GIT when nothing to commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, cherry-pick

I am using VS 2022 and have done a cherry pick.  There is nothing left to resolve and all is up to date and yet it is stuck in cherry pick in progress.  Am I missing something?

Also tried running git cherry-pick --contiue and the result is:

Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

```
You are currently cherry-picking commit ae1e63c0.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: It looks like the result of the cherry-pick was an empty commit..... the instructions that cherry-pick is providing you there are _very_ clear about what to do right now.

Comment: Once I started I picked my changes and accepted them.  Then it says to run git cherry-pick --continue which produces above result.  So not clear, as I don't wish to abort nor cancle my changes.

Comment: well... cherry-pick applies commits _separately_ and will stop if there is a problem (for instance, if there is a conflict.... or if applying the commit will actually not change code).... so, it looks like the commit being applied right now produces no changes on your branch so you can ask to skip it.... or you can abort (which you say you don't want to do) or you can ask to continue..... no fancy stuff here, this is the way cherry-pick (and rebase... and revert) work when there is something to look at.

Comment: @eftshift0 appreciate the response.  That is what I understood it would stop at changes or something wrong, but in my case all conflicts were sorted and accepted and no errors reported anywhere and running git cherry-pick --continue keeps producing the above result not matter how many times I do it.  I would assume as I have accepted conflicts and fixed them then there would be something to commit/update on the branch.  The odd thing is that git desktop tool actually fixes this  and allows me to push my changes whereas VS 2022 just gets stuck on Cherry Pick in progress.

Comment: Would be helpful if VS Git extension shows some more useful message instead of "Cherry-pick in progress"